# crypto-js output is different from node crypto

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs

We are trying to match the crypto and crypto-js output.
Our requirement is to encrypt string in browser but crypto will not support browser side encryption. So, we are trying to match the output using crypto-js. Each time crypto-js produces different output.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');

const payload = {
    name: 'John Doe'
}

// Node Package
function encryptNode(text) {
    const cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc', 'devOps');
    return cipher.update(Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(text)), 'utf8', 'hex') + cipher.final('hex');
}
console.log(encryptNode(payload));


// Browser Package
function encryptBrowser(text) {
    const ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(text), 'devOps', { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC });
    return ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.format.Hex);
}
console.log(encryptBrowser(payload));
```

**Output:**

crypto(Expected): dfe03c7e825e9943aa6ec61deb4a8a73fdba0016a13c59c628ce025f39d44c7c

crypto-js: 4e5453abe7bd53d67d88aa4f040356c649fe0101366d05ce4c7d625cfd052cdc

Comment: Any particular reason you're using two different libs for Node and Browser? Can you use https://github.com/brix/crypto-js for both? It'll give constant results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`crypto.createCipher`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipher_algorithm_password_options) and [`CryptoJS.AES.encrypt`](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-algorithms) utilize the functionality of the OpenSSL-function [`EVP_BytesToKey`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_BytesToKey.html), which expects a password, an *optional* 8-byte salt, a digest and an iteration count, and generates a key and an IV from these data. Both functions use the MD5 digest and an iteration count of 1 as fixed parameters.

`crypto.createCipher` doesn't use a salt, so that the *same* key and IV are generated each time and thus the same ciphertext (assuming the same plaintext).

In contrast, `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt` generates a random salt each time ([here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-output) and [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#interoperability)), so that a *different* key and IV are generated each time, and thus a different ciphertext (even for an identical plaintext). For decryption (beside the password) the salt is needed, which isn't secret and can be passed together with the ciphertext (e.g. in a `CipherParams`-object to `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt`).

The posted code snippet therefore behaves *as expected*: The ciphertext created with `crypto.createCipher` doesn't change, the ciphertext created with `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt` changes each time.

`EVP_BytesToKey` is [weak](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/29139) and shouldn't be used for security reasons (at least when using MD5 and an iteration count of 1). The same applies to `crypto.createCipher` (even more so because of the missing salt), which is deprecated anyway, and that overloaded variant of `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt`, which uses `EVP_BytesToKey`. Both libraries provide additional or overloaded methods to which a key and IV can be passed *directly* (which can be derived from a passphrase beforehand using a secure procedure if required).

Comment: what do you recommend ?

Comment: @LumbusterTick - As already indicated in the answer, I would not use the built-in (insecure) key derivation, but pass the key _directly_. Both libraries support this (_crypto_ via `createCipheriv()` and _CryptoJS_ by passing the key as a `WordArray`). If the key is to be derived from a password, a reliable key derivation function must be used beforehand, e.g. PBKDF2, which is also supported by both libraries.